# Highest rating between two columns in sql select

Tags: php, sql

Say I have the following table:

```
--------------------
|ID|Yes|No|Filename|
|01|15 |10|1.php   |
|02|12 |5 |2.php   |
|03|6  |1 |3.php   |
--------------------
```

What I want to do is apply Yes/Yes+No in an sql select statement and echo the highest value's filename.

The Yes and No are updated from time to time, so would it be better to create another column to handle the equation, or can an equation be used in a sql statment? And what would the select statment look like for this?

Thanks

Comment: what is the database server you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for `MySQL`,

```
SELECT  Filename, 
        CAST((Yes / (Yes + No)) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) rating
FROM    table1
WHERE   CAST((Yes / (Yes + No)) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) =
        (
            SELECT MAX(rating)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT CAST((Yes / (Yes + No)) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) rating
                FROM table1
            ) x
        )
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d191d/5)

for `SQL Server`

```
SELECT   TOP 1 WITH TIES Filename, 
         (Yes / (Yes + No)) rating
FROM     table1
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab12d/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
SELECT TOP 1 sf.Filename
   , (sf.Yes / (sf.Yes + sf.No)) AS RatioValue
FROM dbo.storeFile AS sf
ORDER BY (sf.Yes / (sf.Yes + sf.No)) DESC
```